# System.Runtime.InteropService.COMException thrown and Internet Explorer closes

Tags: c#, shdocvw.internetexplorer

I'm using `SHDocVw.InternetExplorer` to open and control a browser window for automation on an internal website. The software generally performs as desired but the browser will close occasionally. I have tracked down the lines of code that cause it to happen but I'm unable to think of a way to fix the problem.

My original code looked like this:

```
private InternetExplorer window;

public HTMLDocument Document 
{ 
    get 
    {
        try
        {
            return (HTMLDocument)window.Document;
        }
        catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    } 
}
```

However, whenever the the `window.Document` call resulted in a `COMException` the browser would close. I tried creating a isReady boolean that was set to false when I tried to navigate away from the current page and was set true when the `NavigateComplete2` event was fired but it doesn't fire if the browser asks "are you sure you want to leave this page" which meant that I couldn't interact with those popups.

So I tried changing the code to:

```
private InternetExplorer window;

public HTMLDocument Document 
{ 
    get 
    {
        try
        {
            if (window.Busy) return null;
            return (HTMLDocument)window.Document;
        }
        catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    } 
}
```

While I've experienced fewer crashes it will still occasionally close the browser when a `COMException` occurs on the `window.Busy` call.

Since `NavigateComplete2` doesn't fire when the navigation is interrupted by the browser and `InternetExplorer.Busy` can also result in the browser closing I'm out of ideas on how to resolve.

Edit:
I have now also tried: `window.ReadyState == tagREADYSTATE.READYSTATE_COMPLETE` but it throws the same `COMException` on `window.ReadyState` and crashes the windows.